# Как автоматизировать конвертацию h264 в mp4 (rasberry pi)?

Tags: файлы, видео, raspberry-pi

Добрый день! 
Мне необходимо переводить большое количество файлов из формата `h264` в `mp4`. 
На данный момент я меняю имя файла каждый раз. Код выглядит так:

```
$ MP4Box -fps 4 - add file.h264 file.mp4
```

Можно ли как-то сделать так, чтобы имена файла в папке считывались и заменяли названия старого и нового файлов пока файлы не закончатся? Предпологаю, что нужно использовать `globe`, но не понимаю, как передавать имя файла в качестве переменной.

Большое спасибо!

Comment: Имелся в виду [glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming))? И на чём вы собираетесь это автоматизировать, на Bash?

Comment: Да, glob. На Python. Я прошу прощения, если не смогу ответить на некоторые вопросы, я хуже, чем новичок)